# Finding the longest common word in two strings in C Language?

Tags: c, string, comparison

I have had a problem with finding the longest common word in two strings for some time now. First I had an idea of doing it with "isspace" function, but couldn't figure out how to find a common word. Then "strcmp" came to my mind, but so far I was only able to compare two strings. I was thinking of some way to incorporate strcmp and isspace in order to find the different words and then use a temp value to find the longest one, but I couldn't think of the correct code to do so.

```
   #include <stdio.h>

   int strcmp(char s[],char t[]);


 void main()
 {

    char s[20],t[20];
   printf("Type in a string s.\n");
   gets(s);
    printf("Type in a string t.\n");
    gets( t );
   printf("The result of comparison=%d\n",strcmp(s,t));

    return 0;
      }


   int strcmp(char s[],char t[])
  {
   int i;
   for(i=0;s[i]==t[i];i++)
   if(s[i]=='\0')
   return( 0 );
   return(s[i]-t[i]);
   }
```

Please help me with this one. All ideas (and code) are welcomed and appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Edit::

I have been battling with this one for a while and I think I have the solution, however it's a very rigid method. The program has a bug, probably with array "ptrArray1", but I cannot fix it.

```
     #include <stdio.h>
     #include <string.h>
     #include <stdlib.h>


     int returnArrayOfWords (char* str4Parsing, char* arrayParsed[])
       {
// returns the length of array
char seps[]   = " \t\n"; // separators
char *token = NULL;
char *next_token = NULL;
int i = 0;

// Establish string and get the first token:
token = strtok( str4Parsing, seps);

// While there are tokens in "str4Parsing"
while ((token != NULL))
{
    // Get next token:
    arrayParsed[i] = token;
    //printf( " %s\n", arrayParsed[i] );//to be commented
    token = strtok( NULL, seps);
    i++;
}
return i;
      }

      void printArr(char *arr[], int n)
     {
int i;
for ( i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    printf("Element %d is %s \n", i, arr[i]);
}
   }


     void findLargestWord(char *ptrArray1[], int sizeArr1, char              *ptrArray2[], int sizeArr2)
{
int maxLength = 0;
char *wordMaxLength = NULL ;
int i = 0, j = 0;
char *w1 = NULL, *w2 = NULL; /*pointers*/
int currLength1 = 0, currLength2 = 0 ;

//printArr(&ptrArray1[0], sizeArr1);
//printArr(&ptrArray2[0], sizeArr2);

for (i = 0; i < sizeArr1; i++)
    {
    // to find the largest word in the array
    w1 = (ptrArray1[i]); // value of address (ptrArray1 + i)
    currLength1 = strlen(w1);
    //printf("The word from the first string is: %s and its length is : %d \n", w1, currLength1); // check point

    for (j = 0; j < sizeArr2; j++)
        {
        w2 = (ptrArray2[j]); // value of address (ptrArray2 + j)
        currLength2 = strlen(w2);
        //printf("The word from the second string is : %s and its length is : %d \n", w2, currLength2); // check point

        if (strcoll(w1, w2) == 0 && currLength1 == currLength2)
            // compares the strings
            {
            if (currLength2 >= maxLength)
                // in the variable maxLength -> the length of the longest word
                {
                    maxLength = currLength2;
                    wordMaxLength = w2;
                    printf("The largest word for now is : %s and its length is : %d \n", wordMaxLength, maxLength); // check point
                }
            }
        }
    }
printf("The largest word is: %s \n", wordMaxLength);
printf("Its length is: %d \n", maxLength);
    }



     int main ()
      {
int n = 80; /*max number of words in string*/
char arrS1[80], arrS2[80];
char *ptrArray1 = NULL, *ptrArray2 = NULL;
int sizeArr1 = 0, sizeArr2 = 0;

// to allocate memory:
ptrArray1 = (char*)calloc(80, sizeof(char));
if(ptrArray1 == NULL)
{
    printf("Error! Memory for Pointer 1 is not allocated.");
    exit(0);
}

ptrArray2 = (char*)calloc(80, sizeof(char));
if(ptrArray2 == NULL)
{
    printf("Error! Memory for Pointer 2 is not allocated.");
    exit(0);
}

printf("Type your first string: ");
fgets(arrS1, 80, stdin);
sizeArr1 = returnArrayOfWords (arrS1, &ptrArray1); // sizeArr1 = number of elements in array 1

printf("Type your second string: ");
fgets(arrS2, 80, stdin);
sizeArr2 = returnArrayOfWords (arrS2, &ptrArray2); // sizeArr2 = number of elements in array 2

findLargestWord(&ptrArray1, sizeArr1, &ptrArray2, sizeArr2);

free(ptrArray1);
free(ptrArray2);
return 0;
          }
```

I also tried to use the latter two posted soltuions, but I have a problem with working with them as stated below.

Any help with my code, fixing my problems with the latter solutions or coming up with new solutions is welcomed. Thank you all in advance!

PS. I'm sorry if my code is poorly placed. I'm still not very good with using the placement.

Comment: Have you looked at `strspn`? (never use `gets` - it was removed from C in C11 -- and it is a hanging offense...)

Comment: Why are you creating your own [`strcmp`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcmp) function?

Comment: Oh, and don't use `gets`, ever. Besides having been deprecated since the C99 standard, and removed completely in the C11 standard, it's *dangerous* and doesn't protect against buffer overflows.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin `strspn` doesn't seem entirely appropriate here. For `strspn`, the `accept` characters do not need to be in any specific order. So it will return false positives for the OP unless followed up with further comparisons. Unless I'm misunderstanding the OP question or your suggestion.

Comment: `void main()` is implementation-defined. You should use standard `int main(void)` unless you have some special reasons to use the implementation-defined signature.

Comment: The C standard function to parse by delimiters, to tokenise is `strtok()`. However it's a beast, take care ... ;-)

Comment: Ir actually turns out that `strchr` is the one you want for the job.. It makes if fairly easy to step through both strings, identifying any potential substring locations. At that point it is just a matter of which is longer. The answer I did took that approach and seems to mow the grass quite well.

Comment: I'm supposed to use pointers to a function, that's why I have a created a strcmp function.

What else besides gets should I use? fgets?

Thank you all for the help, I will look into those functions.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This example prints the longest substring given two input strings.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int *lcommon(char *str1, char *str2) {
    int strlen1 = (unsigned) strlen(str1);
    int strlen2 = (unsigned) strlen(str2);
    int i, j, k;
    int longest = 0;
    int **ptr = malloc(2 * sizeof(int *));
    static int *ret;
    ret = calloc((unsigned) strlen1 + 1, sizeof(int));
    for (i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        ptr[i] = calloc((unsigned) strlen2, sizeof(int));

    k = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < strlen1; i++) {
        memcpy(ptr[0], ptr[1], strlen2 * sizeof(int));
        for (j = 0; j < strlen2; j++) {
            if (str1[i] == str2[j]) {
                if (i == 0 || j == 0) {
                    ptr[1][j] = 1;
                } else {
                    ptr[1][j] = ptr[0][j-1] + 1;
                }
                if (ptr[1][j] > longest) {
                    longest = ptr[1][j];
                    k = 0;
                    ret[k++] = longest;
                }
                if (ptr[1][j] == longest) {
                    ret[k++] = i;
                    ret[k] = -1;
                }
            } else {
                ptr[1][j] = 0;
            }
        }
    }
    for (i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        free(ptr[i]);
    free(ptr);
    ret[0] = longest;
    return ret;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int i, longest, *ret;

    if (argc != 3) {
        printf("usage: longest-common-substring string1 string2\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    ret = lcommon(argv[1], argv[2]);
    if ((longest = ret[0]) == 0) {
        printf("There is no common substring\n");
        exit(2);
    }

    i = 0;
    while (ret[++i] != -1) {
        printf("%.*s\n", longest, &argv[1][ret[i]-longest+1]);
    }

    exit(0);
}
```

**Test**

```
$ ./a.out computerprogramming javaprogrammer
programm
```

You can read more about the problem [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_substring_problem).

You can also use an interactive program where you write the strings in the console:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int *lcommon(char *str1, char *str2) {
    int strlen1 = (unsigned) strlen(str1);
    int strlen2 = (unsigned) strlen(str2);
    int i, j, k;
    int longest = 0;
    int **ptr = malloc(2 * sizeof(int *));
    static int *ret;
    ret = calloc((unsigned) strlen1 + 1, sizeof(int));
    for (i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        ptr[i] = calloc((unsigned) strlen2, sizeof(int));

    k = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < strlen1; i++) {
        memcpy(ptr[0], ptr[1], strlen2 * sizeof(int));
        for (j = 0; j < strlen2; j++) {
            if (str1[i] == str2[j]) {
                if (i == 0 || j == 0) {
                    ptr[1][j] = 1;
                } else {
                    ptr[1][j] = ptr[0][j - 1] + 1;
                }
                if (ptr[1][j] > longest) {
                    longest = ptr[1][j];
                    k = 0;
                    ret[k++] = longest;
                }
                if (ptr[1][j] == longest) {
                    ret[k++] = i;
                    ret[k] = -1;
                }
            } else {
                ptr[1][j] = 0;
            }
        }
    }
    for (i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        free(ptr[i]);
    free(ptr);
    ret[0] = longest;
    return ret;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int i, longest, *ret;

    if (argc != 3) {
        //printf("usage: longest-common-substring string1 string2\n");

        char s[20], t[20];
        printf("Type in a string s.\n");
        fgets(s, 20, stdin);
        printf("Type in a string t.\n");
        fgets(t, 20, stdin);

        ret = lcommon(s, t);
        if ((longest = ret[0]) == 0) {
            printf("There is no common substring\n");
            exit(2);
        }

        i = 0;
        while (ret[++i] != -1) {
            printf("%.*s\n", longest, &s[ret[i] - longest + 1]);
        }

        //printf("The result of comparison=%d\n", strcmp(s, t));


        exit(0);
    } else { }
    ret = lcommon(argv[1], argv[2]);
    if ((longest = ret[0]) == 0) {
        printf("There is no common substring\n");
        exit(2);
    }

    i = 0;
    while (ret[++i] != -1) {
        printf("%.*s\n", longest, &argv[1][ret[i] - longest + 1]);
    }
    exit(0);
}
```

**Test**

```
Type in a string s.
string1
Type in a string t.
string2
string
```

Comment: You do not want to cast the result of `malloc()` & Friends in C.

Comment: Also `strlen()` returns `size_t` not `int`.

Comment: @alk Thank you for the comments. I tried to fix the code accordingly. Please have a look again if you agree.

Comment: Thank you for your help, but I do not quite understand your code. It just prints out   "usage: longest-common-substring string1 string2". Am I supposed to add printf-scanf statements around?

Comment: Beowolf, you can supply the strings as arguments i e ./a.out mystring1 mystring2

Comment: Supply the strings as arguments?

Comment: @BeowulfDragonheart Yes, you compile the program and then you write the strings as arguments to the program when you start the program. I also updated the answer with a new version of the program where you can write the strings on the console same way you did in your example. I hope this clarifies...You can either supply the 2 strings as arguments to the program when starting the program, or write the string to the program once it is started.

Comment: @Programmer 400 This time it works perfectly. Thank you so much, this problem really got the best of me. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

There are a large number of ways to approach the problem. Below, a pointer to each character in one of the strings is used to search the other for matching characters using `strchr`. After matching characters are found, a comparison loop runs advancing each of the pointers to devise the length of the common substring present, if any.

The routine, match characters, check substring length, repeat, continues so longs as `strchr` returns a valid pointer.Each time a longer substring is found, the `max` length is updated for return and the substring present is copied to `r` with `strncpy` and *nul-terminated* so that the text of the longest common string is available to the calling function, `main` here.

This is a rather brute force method, and there may be a few additional tweaks to improve efficiency. The function itself is:

```
/** return length of longest common substring in 'a' and 'b'.
 *  by searching through each character in 'a' for each match
 *  in 'b' and comparing substrings present at each match. the
 *  size of the longest substring is returned, the test of the
 *  longest common substring is copied to 'r' and made available
 *  in the calling function. (the lengths should also be passed
 *  for validation, but that is left as an exercise)
 */
size_t maxspn (const char *a, const char *b, char *r)
{
    if (!a||!b||!*a||!*b) return 0; /* valdate parameters */

    char *ap = (char *)a;           /* pointer to a       */
    size_t max = 0;                 /* max substring char */

    for (; *ap; ap++) {             /* for each char in a */
        char *bp = (char *)b;       /* find match in b with strchr */
        for (; *bp && (bp = strchr (bp, *ap)); bp++) {
            char *spa = ap, *spb = bp; /* search ptr initialization */
            size_t len = 0;         /* find substring len */
            for (; *spa && *spb && *spa == *spb; spa++, spb++) len++;
            if (len > max) {        /* if max, copy to r  */
                strncpy (r, ap, (max = len));
                r[max] = 0;         /* nul-terminate r    */
            }
        }
    }

    return max;
}
```

The length `max` is returned, and then updates to `r` during function execution cause `r` to hold the string associated with the longest substring match.

Additional improvements were to remove `gets` which was removed in C11 without deprecation due to its security risk. It should no longer be used by any sane coder (that should cover about 40% of us). Putting the remaining bits together, a small bit of test code could be:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAXC 128

size_t maxspn (const char *a, const char *b, char *r);
void rmlf (char *s);

int main (void) {

    char res[MAXC] = "", s[MAXC] = "", t[MAXC] = "";

    printf ("Type in a string 's': ");
    if (!fgets (s, MAXC, stdin)) {  /* validate 's' */
        fprintf (stderr, "error: invalid input for 's'.\n");
        return 1;
    }
    rmlf (s);   /* remove trailing newline */
    printf ("Type in a string 't': ");
    if (!fgets (t, MAXC, stdin)) {  /* validate 't' */
        fprintf (stderr, "error: invalid input for 's'.\n");
        return 1;
    }
    rmlf (t);   /* remove trailing newline */

    /* obtain longest commons substring between 's' and 't' */
    printf ("\nThe longest common string is : %zu ('%s')\n",
            maxspn (s, t, res), res);

    return 0;
}

/** return length of longest common substring in 'a' and 'b'.
 *  by searching through each character in 'a' for each match
 *  in 'b' and comparing substrings present at each match. the
 *  size of the longest substring is returned, the test of the
 *  longest common substring is copied to 'r' and made available
 *  in the calling function. (the lengths should also be passed
 *  for validation, but that is left as an exercise)
 */
size_t maxspn (const char *a, const char *b, char *r)
{
    if (!a||!b||!*a||!*b) return 0; /* valdate parameters */

    char *ap = (char *)a;           /* pointer to a       */
    size_t max = 0;                 /* max substring char */

    for (; *ap; ap++) {             /* for each char in a */
        char *bp = (char *)b;       /* find match in b with strchr */
        for (; *bp && (bp = strchr (bp, *ap)); bp++) {
            char *spa = ap, *spb = bp;
            size_t len = 0;         /* find substring len */
            for (; *spa && *spb && *spa == *spb; spa++, spb++) len++;
            if (len > max) {        /* if max, copy to r  */
                strncpy (r, ap, (max = len));
                r[max] = 0;         /* nul-terminate r    */
            }
        }
    }

    return max;
}

/** remove trailing newline from 's'. */
void rmlf (char *s)
{
    if (!s || !*s) return;
    for (; *s && *s != '\n'; s++) {}
    *s = 0;
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/strspn
Type in a string 's': a string with colors123456789 all blue
Type in a string 't': a string without colors1234567890 all red

The longest common string is : 16 (' colors123456789')
```

or, another that may be easier to visualize:

```
$ ./bin/strspn
Type in a string 's': green eel
Type in a string 't': cold blue steel

The longest common string is : 3 ('eel')
```

Look over the code and compare with the other answers. Let me know if you have any additional questions. There are a few other validations that should be added to insure text is not written beyond the ends of buffers, etc.. Hopefully this will provide a bit of help or an alternative approach.

---

**Additional Substrings**

Just to make sure you and I are seeing the same thing, I have included additional examples of use below. There is no error, and the code preforms as intended. If you are having trouble modifying the code, please let me know what you are attempting to do and I can help. Each of the pointer increments in my code above are validated. If you change anything regarding the pointer increment or *nul-termination*, the code will not work unless you account for the changes in the validations as well.

```
$ ./bin/strspn
Type in a string 's': 1
Type in a string 't':

The longest common string is : 0 ('')

$ ./bin/strspn
Type in a string 's': A man a plan a canal panama
Type in a string 't': a man a plan a river panama

The longest common string is : 14 (' man a plan a ')

$ ./bin/strspn
Type in a string 's': this is my favorite string
Type in a string 't': this is my favoritist string

The longest common string is : 18 ('this is my favorit')

$ ./bin/strspn
Type in a string 's': not the same until here
Type in a string 't': cant be equal till here

The longest common string is : 6 ('l here')

$ ./bin/strspn
Type in a string 's': some str with ten in the middle
Type in a string 't': a string often ignorded

The longest common string is : 5 ('ten i')
```

---

**Longest Common Word**

OK, after I finally understand what you are trying to accomplish, you can select the *longest common word* between the two strings `'s'` and `'t'` by *tokenizing* each string with `strtok`, saving a pointer to each word in each string in separate pointer arrays, and then simply iterating over the pointer arrays to select the longest common word (1st if multiple common words of the same length). Something as simple as the following is all you need.

**NOTE** `strtok` modifies the strings `'s'` and `'t'`, so make a copy if you need to preserve the originals.

```
/** return length of longest common word in 'a' and 'b'.
 *  by tokenizing each word in 'a' & 'b' and iterating over
 *  each, returning the length of the logest match, and updating
 *  'r' to contain the longest common word.
 */
size_t maxspnwhole (char *a, char *b, char *r)
{
    if (!a||!b||!*a||!*b) return 0; /* valdate parameters */

    char *arra[MAXC] = {NULL}, *arrb[MAXC] = {NULL};
    char *ap = a, *bp = b;          /* pointers to a & b */
    char *delim = " .,-;\t\n";      /* word delimiters   */
    size_t i, j, len, max, na, nb;  /* len, max, n-words */
    len = max = na = nb = 0;

    /* tokenize both strings into pointer arrays */
    for (ap = strtok (a, delim); ap; ap = strtok (NULL, delim))
        arra[na++] = ap;

    for (bp = strtok (b, delim); bp; bp = strtok (NULL, delim))
        arrb[nb++] = bp;

    for (i = 0; i < na; i++)           /* select longest common word */
        for (j = 0; j < nb; j++)
            if (*arra[i] == *arrb[j])             /* 1st chars match */
                if (!strcmp (arra[i], arrb[j])) { /* check word      */
                    len = strlen (arra[i]);
                    if (len > max) {              /* if longest */
                        max = len;                /* update max */
                        strcpy (r, arra[i]);      /* copy to r  */
                    }
                }

    return max;
}
```

Integrating it with the other code, you can compare the results like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAXC 128

size_t maxspn (const char *a, const char *b, char *r);
size_t maxspnwhole (char *a, char *b, char *r);
void rmlf (char *s);

int main (void) {

    char res[MAXC] = "", s[MAXC] = "", t[MAXC] = "";

    printf ("Type in a string 's': ");
    if (!fgets (s, MAXC, stdin)) {  /* validate 's' */
        fprintf (stderr, "error: invalid input for 's'.\n");
        return 1;
    }
    rmlf (s);   /* remove trailing newline */
    printf ("Type in a string 't': ");
    if (!fgets (t, MAXC, stdin)) {  /* validate 't' */
        fprintf (stderr, "error: invalid input for 's'.\n");
        return 1;
    }
    rmlf (t);   /* remove trailing newline */

    /* obtain longest commons substring between 's' and 't' */
    printf ("\nThe longest common string is : %zu ('%s')\n",
            maxspn (s, t, res), res);

    /* obtain longest commons word between 's' and 't' */
    printf ("\nThe longest common word is : %zu ('%s')\n",
            maxspnwhole (s, t, res), res);

    return 0;
}

/** return length of longest common word in 'a' and 'b'.
 *  by tokenizing each word in 'a' & 'b' and iterating over
 *  each, returning the length of the logest match, and updating
 *  'r' to contain the longest common word.
 */
size_t maxspnwhole (char *a, char *b, char *r)
{
    if (!a||!b||!*a||!*b) return 0; /* valdate parameters */

    char *arra[MAXC] = {NULL}, *arrb[MAXC] = {NULL};
    char *ap = a, *bp = b;          /* pointers to a & b */
    char *delim = " .,-;\t\n";      /* word delimiters   */
    size_t i, j, len, max, na, nb;  /* len, max, n-words */
    len = max = na = nb = 0;

    /* tokenize both strings into pointer arrays */
    for (ap = strtok (a, delim); ap; ap = strtok (NULL, delim))
        arra[na++] = ap;

    for (bp = strtok (b, delim); bp; bp = strtok (NULL, delim))
        arrb[nb++] = bp;

    for (i = 0; i < na; i++)
        for (j = 0; j < nb; j++)
            if (*arra[i] == *arrb[j])
                if (!strcmp (arra[i], arrb[j])) {
                    len = strlen (arra[i]);
                    if (len > max) {
                        max = len;
                        strcpy (r, arra[i]);
                    }
                }

    return max;
}

/** return length of longest common substring in 'a' and 'b'.
 *  by searching through each character in 'a' for each match
 *  in 'b' and comparing substrings present at each match. the
 *  size of the longest substring is returned, the test of the
 *  longest common substring is copied to 'r' and made available
 *  in the calling function. (the lengths should also be passed
 *  for validation, but that is left as an exercise)
 */
size_t maxspn (const char *a, const char *b, char *r)
{
    if (!a||!b||!*a||!*b) return 0; /* valdate parameters */

    char *ap = (char *)a;           /* pointer to a       */
    size_t max = 0;                 /* max substring char */

    for (; *ap; ap++) {             /* for each char in a */
        char *bp = (char *)b;       /* find match in b with strchr */
        for (; *bp && (bp = strchr (bp, *ap)); bp++) {
            char *spa = ap, *spb = bp;
            size_t len = 0;         /* find substring len */
            for (; *spa && *spb && *spa == *spb; spa++, spb++) len++;
            if (len > max) {        /* if max, copy to r  */
                strncpy (r, ap, (max = len));
                r[max] = 0;         /* nul-terminate r    */
            }
        }
    }

    return max;
}

/** remove trailing newline from 's'. */
void rmlf (char *s)
{
    if (!s || !*s) return;
    for (; *s && *s != '\n'; s++) {}
    *s = 0;
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/strlongestcmn
Type in a string 's': I have a huge boat.
Type in a string 't': I have a small boat.

The longest common string is : 9 ('I have a ')

The longest common word is : 4 ('have')
```

Look it over and let me know if you have any further questions.

Comment: You program seems much better than any of my attempts so far. I have to admit I couldn't pay much attention the last couple of days to this forum, because of personal reasons. However, I tested the program and each time I enter two strings, it crashes and I have no idea why. It just no longer responds. Could you help me out with this, please?

Comment: Sure, give me a bit and I'll take a look in a couple of hours.

Comment: Give me an example of how you enter the strings. You are waiting for the prompts for the string, right?  I just ran though possible inputs from inputs for `a`, none for `b`, numbers, single-letter entries, long entries, and I cannot reproduce. Show me what you entered that causes the code to no longer respond.

Comment: Thank you for the help, but Programmer 400 already found a solution to my problem. I wouldn't want to occupy you with it anymore.

To answer to you question - I just enter two random strings in the prompts you created and once the program receives both strings, it just crashes.

Comment: Glad you got it sorted out. I cannot see how you could be experiencing a crash. I would be worth you copying and pasting my post again (verbatim) and giving it a go. If you are on windows, you might try changing the loop in `rmlf` to `for (; *s && *s != '\n' && *s != '\r'; s++) {}` which shouldn't be needed, but if you have a stray *carriage-return* that could cause problems.

Comment: I changed the code so it works with whole words, not only substrings, but it gives an error. The error is on this line of code `strncpy (r, ap, (max = len));`. Could you please tell me what you think about it?

Comment: `for (; *bp && (bp = strchr (bp, *ap)); bp++) {
   spa = ap;
   spb = bp;
   len = 0;    /* find substring len */
   for (; *spa && *spb && *spa == *spb && *spa != '\0' && *spb != '\0'; spa++, spb++) len++;
   if (len > max) {        /* if max, copy to r  */
    strncpy (r, ap, (max = len));
   }
   if (*spa == '\0' && *spb == '\0')
    { r[max] = '\0';         /* nul-terminate r    */
     max = len+1;}}}
 return max;}`   
This is the changed piece of code. PS. I'm sorry for the bad formatting, I simply cannot change it otherwise.

Comment: I'll look. While I'm looking, add `fprintf (stderr, "len: %zu max: %zu, ap : %s\n", len, max, ap);`  before `strncpy` and check the values for `len`, `max` and `ap`.

Comment: Your code was ` for (; *spa && *spb && *spa == *spb; spa++, spb++) len++;` and my code is `for (; *spa && *spb && *spa == *spb && *spa != '\0' && *spb != '\0'; spa++, spb++) len++;` at line 61 and `if (*spa == '\0' && *spb == '\0')
    { r[max] = '\0';         /* nul-terminate r    */
     max = len+1;}}}` at lines 65-67

Comment: I've got the original. The biggest issue is (1) your `}` are unbalanced in `}}}` (you have one too many); (2) you *must* place `r[max] = '\0';` (which is equivalent to `r[max] = 0;`) immediately after `strncpy` because `strncpy` does not guarantee *nul-termiantion*. No need for `max = len+1;` (which will cause error) if you want to update if the strings are the same length, do it with `if (len >= max)`. Remember each pointer `ap, bp, spa, spb` are incremented to point *exactly* to the character of interest, and are *validated* accordingly, anything that changes a pointer must be accounted for.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with your changes? If I know where you are going, I can probably save you a bit of time, and a lot of code...

Comment: The program should return a whole word, that's why Im making those changes right now. I did as you advised me above - changed the place of `r[max] = '\0';` and put `if (len >= max)` and the program still gives an error.

Comment: Oh, that's no problem. My understanding was you wanted the longest equivalent substring. If you want it to begin and end on a word, then you just need to add a check against the *tokens* you consider valid word separators (e.g. `" .,\t\n-"`, etc..). We can also just tokenize the strings input with `strtok` and search for similar whole-word substrings. Let me know if it should start `and` end on whole words only or just `begin` on whole words.

Comment: The point is to find only one common word from the two strings. Example: 
I caught a fish.
He was caught in the trap.
The longest common word is "caught". It should start and end on this word. I have been thinking about `isspace` and `strtok`, but frankly, I do not how to employ them successfully here.

Comment: By the way, I work on a windows 7 and after the crash of the program I get this message in the command prompt: "Process return 1073741819 (0XC0000005)" if that helps with identifying where the problem may be.

Comment: What if there are 2 common words? Pick the first?

Comment: Pick the longest. And if there are two equal length common words, pick the first. Example: I have a huge boat. I have a small boat. --> print have as the common word.

Comment: Yes, the program works perfectly! Thank you so much for your help, you saved me countless hours of struggling with that beast.

Comment: Glad it helps. C takes a bit of extra effort to learn, but it is time well spent. The key to learning C is just to *slow down*, spend the time needed to understand each line, each char, in your code and what exactly they are doing (even if it takes longer than you think it should). There are no shortcuts. If you learn C, really learn it, there is nothing you cannot do in programming.